# Javascript: How to recursively return a counter?

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the example below, I don't want to make a counter as a param.  Rather, I just want to return '+ 1' each time so that what gets returned is the number of steps it takes.  My issue lies with the base case. If I do `return + 1`, I get the correct number of steps plus one additional step so I tried just `return` but that delivers `NaN`.  Is it even possible?

```js
var numberOfSteps  = function(num) {

    if (num == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            return 1 + numberOfSteps(num/2);
        } else {
            return 1 + numberOfSteps(num - 1);
        }
    }
};
```

**edit** : The goal is to track how many steps it takes to reduce a number to 0.  If it's even, divide by 2 or else subtract by 1.  Ultimately, I want to return the number of steps it takes for any given number to get reduced to 0 following those rules

Comment: `return num;` ?

Comment: But that implies the recursion ends when num is 0 which is not very useful

Comment: Don't add one? ... Right now you're not returning *anything*--if you don't want to add anything, and `num` is `0`, then return `num` (or just `0`). It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do though.

Comment: @GuerricP Why isn't that useful? `num` is decreasing, what else would you do at `0`?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm just saying that `if (num == 0) return num` is just returning 0 whatever the recursion has done.

Comment: @GuerricP Sure, it could just be `return 0`, but the "implication" that the recursion ends when num is 0 seems correct, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, I added more specifics at the bottom on what I am trying to do.  Also, making it `return num` does work -- I just don't know why.  It's a bit confusing having `if (num == 0) return num` return something other than `0` since that is what num is equal to

Comment: @burtonLowel If `num == 0` it will only ever return `0`. You can *explicitly* return `0` but the behavior is identical because `num == 0`.

Comment: Unrelated, but I personally favor "flattening" code when possible: code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is. E.g., https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/10be5dceb899986bc4ce833846d8df16

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton .  But by what you're saying: "If num == 0 it will only ever return 0", how/why does `return num` return the number of steps rather than 0.

Comment: @DaveNewton I actually don't like short-circuiting code with return statements like that. I prefer having one return statement at the end of the function

Comment: @burtonLowel It doesn't. When it's called with `0` (i.e., `num === 0`), it returns `0`. When it is *not* called with `0`, it returns a value based on the other conditions. Personally--I'd take a step back and start with an easier recursion example (e.g., Fibonacci, etc.) and trace it out with pencil and paper.

Comment: @Codebling Cool. Followed slavishly that rule leads to higher cognitive overheads: it *requires* you to read the entire function in order to understand what's happening. My own preference is to understand what's happening as early as possible. YMMV.

Comment: thanks @DaveNewton, much appreciated!

Comment: @DaveNewton perhaps a discussion to be had in a chat somewhere sometime, but I do it because if something goes wrong, it's easier to put a breakpoint and check values before return than it is to find every return statement and put a breakpoint on it. I don't mind the extra indentation, it's maybe a reminder that one shouldn't have 20 nested layers of IFs. Again not really a discussion we need to have here, but if  it's advice to a beginner it's nice to have both sides of the argument; that's the only reason I left that comment

Comment: @Codebling Meh. If you're debugging a function (which we agree should be short and focused), break on entry, and single-step. If you care only about the return value break on the call, not on the return. If you care how it's being calculated you have to break at the start of the function anyway. But agreed--it's always good to have. multiple points of view (even if yours is wrong ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton fair enough :)

Comment: @burtonLowel now I understand you want to return the number of steps and not the final value, I've provided a solution

Answer (score 3):

I hope the point has gotten through in the long comment thread and other answers that `return + 1` is equivalent to `return (+1)`, that is, return the integer *positive one*.  And since there are no steps to take once you've reached zero, `+1` is the wrong answer.  Similarly, a plain `return` is functionally equivalent to `return undefined`.  But `undefined` is not a number, and you're going to run into problems if you later try to add `1` to it.  So the solution from the comments or other answers to return the correct number of steps, which in this case `0`, will fix your code.

I would like to point out another way to solve this, though:

```js
const numberOfSteps = (n) =>
  n <= 0
    ? 0
    : 1 + numberOfSteps (n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : n - 1)

console .log (numberOfSteps (12))
```

There are superficial differences here from the other solutions, such as using an arrow function, using a conditional statement (ternary) rather than `if`-statements, and using `<= 0` instead of `< 0` to avoid possible infinite loops on negative numbers.

But the fundamental difference is that this code only has one recursive branch.  I think this is a better match to the problem.

We can think of this as a function which answers "How many steps does it take to reach `0` from our input number if each step cuts even numbers in half and subtracts one from odd ones?"  Well that logically leads to a base case (we're already at `0`) so have to return `0`, and a recursive one (we're at some positive integer) so have to add `1` to the total steps required from our next entry.

By doing this single recursive call and adding one to the result, we make it clearer what the recursion is doing.

If this is unclear, then this alternative might show what I mean:

```js
const takeStep = (n) =>
  n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : n - 1

const numberOfSteps = (n) =>
  n <= 0
    ? 0
    : 1 + numberOfSteps (takeStep (n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Think you just need to return `0` when it's...zero.

```
var numberOfSteps  = function(num) {

    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            return 1 + numberOfSteps(num/2);
        } else {
            return 1 + numberOfSteps(num - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

`return + 1` maybe doesn't do what you think it does: it returns the number 1. `+` here means positive not negative, there is no addition or subtraction going on. It will also give you one too many steps.

`return;` by itself returns `undefined`, which when converted to a Number, translates to `NaN`, because, well, it's not a number.

Comment: When downvoting, please be so kind as to indicate the reason.